# Linq: read node innertext

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

i have a xml document like this:

```
<ns:a xmlns:ns="http://NS1">
  <ns:b>
    <c xmlns="http://differentNS"> c_text </c>
    <x xmlns="http://differentNS"> Wanted </x>
    <d xmlns="http://differentNS"> d_text </d>
  </ns:b>
</ns:a>
```

Now i want to use linq to read the element's "x" inner text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation using LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<ns:a xmlns:ns='http://NS1'><ns:b><c xmlns='http://differentNS'>c_text</c><x xmlns='http://differentNS'>Wanted</x><d xmlns='http://differentNS'>d_text</d></ns:b></ns:a>");

XNamespace ns = "http://differentNS";
var result = doc.Descendants(ns + "x").Single().Value
```

**Related resources:**

- [XDocument.Parse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse(v=VS.100).aspx)
- [XContainer.Descendants method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: doc.Descendants returns an IEnumerable<XElement> which don't have the Value property. What cast should i do?

Comment: You are right. You need to select the single XElement in the list in order to extract the value. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(yourdocumenthere);
var myvalue = xDocument.Element("ns:a").element("ns:b").element("c").value;
```

This isn't using link, but is still very simple.

Comment: Yes, it's simple but only works with no namespaces. If i write "ns:a" i receive the exception "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."